# VBA to validate use of correct (updated) version of a file

Tags: vba, excel

Vendors are sent an excel workbook that they add data to and send back. Recently, we made some changes to this file (some data validation fields) that inhibit users from adding incorrect data. BUT...i've found that vendors are just using the old file because it doesn't contain these annoying validation features.
I'm attempting to add a function to an uploading macro that basically checks that the file is the current version (the one with validation).

I thought about adding a hidden worksheet to the new file and doing a simple count through to check the presence of this worksheet. Like below

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Validation" Then
    exists = True
    End If
Next i

If Not exists Then
exit sub
End If
```

Another option might be to add some type of signature to the code and check for the presence of that signature before uploading. I'm open to new ideas on how to tackle this just looking for creative ideas.

thanks for your help!

Comment: We could tag the document with some custom property. Here is the link reference for add/remove and reading document property - [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by uploading? Uploading to where? How do the vendors send you the excel file back?

Comment: @tehscript So once the data in the file is verified accurate the uploading macro appends to a table in Access. Vendors send  completed files on a weekly basis to a group email.

Comment: I believe your problem is on the business side instead of technical side. You should strictly ask your vendors to use the new excel workbook, otherwise you will end up doing their job instead of them. Where you are heading is more code, moving away from your real objectives, more problems on your way, and probably unexpected errors as well.

Comment: @tehscript Haha trust me I’ve asked them to use the updated file multiple times (and most do) but some are still being stubborn. The uploading macro previously discussed unfortunately doesn’t recognize the difference between the old file and the new one...hence my need for this question. So far I like Nagarajan’s idea. I’m going to give this question some more time for answers before I pull an Oprah and start handing out +1s

Comment: Is the uploading macro in Access? How does it work? Do you open the workbooks  to read the data in it or not?

Comment: Yup...it opens each file individually, checks a range for red conditions, then (assuming there were no red cells) opens a connection with Access and appends each row to a table. Also it’s worth mentioning the conditional formatting is present on both the original and the new file. The data validation rules exist only on the new.

Comment: If you have data validation, you should have a relational table in Access consisting of these data, connected with a foreign key to your main table. While inserting the data in Excel to Access, use a subquery where you can validate the data against the validation table in access. If an error occurs, handle it within your code so that you will know if the vendors are using the old workbook.

Comment: An example: `"INSERT INTO main_table (validation_column, column2, ...) VALUES ((SELECT validation_id FROM validation_table WHERE validation_name = " & Cells(i,j).Value & "), value2, ...);"`

Comment: Interesting... I see how that that would work but if the error occurred only on a cell towards the bottom of the range it would have already uploaded the previous records before it finds the error. Is that correct? When in fact if an error is found (even at the last record) the entire file must be sent back to the vendor. again correct me if that’s not accurate

Comment: Using this idea, you can check it before inserting as well. I think you've got the idea. Good luck with your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should better write it down as an answer.

If you have data validation, you should have a relational table in Access consisting of these data, connected with a foreign key to your main table. While inserting the data in Excel to Access, use a sub-query where you can validate the data against the validation table in access. If an error occurs, handle it within your code so that you will know if the vendors are using the old workbook.

An example:

```
"INSERT INTO main_table (validation_column, column2, ...) 
VALUES ((SELECT validation_id FROM validation_table WHERE validation_name = " & Cells(i,j).Value & "), value2, ...);"
```